# Can I create a resource route with {store}/products?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

so I have this route in the meantime, and I want to change it to

```
Route::resource('{store}/products', 'ProductsController', [
        function($store) {
            $store = App\Models\Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
        }
    ]);
```

is this correct? what would my controller functions look like? should I add $store in each functions I am going to use?

or should I do the long way where I have to do it like Route::get, Route::post...

EDIT: or should I do a Route::group?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve? both have very different purposes.

Comment: @itachi I want to make a resource route like this Route::resource('{store}/products', 'ProductsController', [ but I don't know how to do that